# Making a highly customizable method, or a specific method that does a task?

Tags: structure

I'm not really sure how I would phrase the title right, so I apologize for the initial confusion.

This is just a small question I had about how to structure code and such and I have no idea on what to call it so I will explain it with this example:

Say I am writing a Call of Duty type game where the player can customize their weapons with certain attachment.

I have a class that defines each gun. It looks something like this:

```
class Gun {

int clip = 30;
int ammo = 100;
float reloadTime = 5f;
float damage = 10f;
Attachment[] attachments;
//Plus some not included attachments.

void shoot() {
  //...
}

void reload() {
  //...
}

void applyAllAttachments() {
  //Apply the list of attachments' effects
}

}

class Attachment {
void effect() {
//change the gun in some way.
}

}
```

Now I would like to add 4 attachments, Fast Mags (increase reload speed), Hollow Point (increase damage), Grenade Launcher (Secondary Gun) and Minigun (Replace the barrel with a minigun or something).

For the Fast Mags and the Hollow Point, it should be simple, all I have to do is change a number or a value, but for the Grenade Launcher and Minigun, which have custom, extra functions (like Unity Delegates), would it be wiser to add a function that handles external custom firing types, or would it be better to just have separate methods inside the Gun class that specifically handle to extra minigun functions?

**TL;DR**

If I want to add a grenade launcher attachment to a gun, should I do this:

```
class Gun {

int clip = 30;
int ammo = 100;
float reloadTime = 5f;
float damage = 10f;
Attachment[] attachments = Attachment[10];
//Plus some not included attachments.

void shoot() {
  //...
  customShoot();
}
void customShoot() {
    //Apply attachments custom attachment shoot methods.
}

void reload() {
  //...
}

void applyAllAttachments() {
  //Apply the list of attachments' effects
}

}

class GrenadeLauncher extends Attachment {
@Override
public void effect() {
//Spawn new grenade
}

}
```

Or This:

```
class Gun {

int clip = 30;
int ammo = 100;
float reloadTime = 5f;
float damage = 10f;
Attachment[] attachments = Attachment[10];
//Plus some not included attachments.

void shoot() {
  //...
  if (attachments.GetType() == GrenadeLauncher) {
      grenadeLauncherShoot();
  }
}
void grenadeLauncherShoot() {

}

void reload() {
  //...
}

void applyAllAttachments() {
  //Apply the list of attachments' effects
}

}
```

Sorry for my pseudo/java code, hope it's comprehensible.

Comment: both ways work, I do it the second way

Comment: The first way is more extensible. Your gun should never care what attachments it has on it, only that it had at least zero (a list) and on any action that might have an attachment affect, you ask all attachments about their effect on that action. (Also, `customShoot()` is unnecessary).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first way is better: You can create new attachments without having to modify the Gun class.

In a general manner, you shouldn't need to check for type, and your code will be cleaner if you don't.

Here, your Attachment class should be abstract (I suppose it already is), and force children to implements some functions.

```
public abstract class Attachment
{
    protected abstract void shoot();
}
```

Then the gun calls it for all Attachements:

```
class Gun {
    int clip = 30;
    int ammo = 100;
    float reloadTime = 5f;
    float damage = 10f;
    Attachment[] attachments = Attachment[10];
    //Plus some not included attachments.

    void shoot() {
        //...
        for(int i = 0; i < attachments.length(); ++i) {
            attachments[i].shoot();
        }
    }

    void reload() {
      //...
    }
}

class GrenadeLauncher extends Attachment {
    @Override
    public void shoot() 
    {
        //Spawn new grenade
    }
}
```

By the way, why did you tag java and Unity? If you work with unity your code should be c# or javascript

Comment: Well, the thing that I am doing kind of reminds me of the Unity Delegate system and I kind of sort of wrote the code in java, but other than that idk, I'll remove the tags if that helps.

Comment: I see your point, the link between C# (used in Unity) and java is that both are Object Oriented languages. Polymorphism (the fact of using the same method with different effect depending on type) is a basic concept of object-oriented programming (oop). You can maybe add the "oop" tag. But this is up you, your question is already clear. I was just confused by seeing "java" and "unity" together

Comment: Also, I saw in your profile that you never **accepted** an answer to questions you ask. This is alright if you don't think these question have been properly answered. But just in case, here is the [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) on how and why to do it